# Not able to get the default action bar in AppTheme android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest, android-toolbar

I am not able to get the default action bar which is shown . I have layout AppTheme and i don't know why i am not able to get the default action bar which i shown.

Here is the manifest-

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

And here is styles.xml--

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Here is the pic of what the problem is-

[image: I am not able to get the action bar]

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: If you run the app, is there a Toolbar? Why do you think the preview should have the toolbar?

Comment: @cricket_007 Not able to get what you mean to say.Please explain.

Comment: Actually run the app on a device. You are looking at a preview of the layout (which has no Toolbar itself)

Comment: I will run it one a device but i want the action bar should be displayed aswell in the preview. Because normally when you do it you always get the action bar in the preview aswell. Moreover if i select any other theme i can see the action bar. But when i use AppTheme it disappears

Comment: Then you need to use something other than `parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light"`

Comment: Let me try if it works.

Comment: For example, use a NoActionBar theme, then you add `<Toolbar>` into the XML layout yourself.

Comment: I tried using  parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" didn't work

Comment: I really don't know how to add and customize the toolbar.

Comment: You can use parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"  will shows you Actionbar in preview.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html

Comment: It is unclear what you are referencing that uses `Base.Theme...`

Comment: @PranavDarji and cricket_007 Thanks for your help now it is working.